# redirecting /directory/ to www.example.com

Tags: .htaccess

I'm attempting to redirect /fourm/ on my website back to http://www.example.com

I've come up with this:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteRule /forum/(.*) http://www.path.com(.*) [R=301,L]
```

However it doesn't work, any thoughts appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there you just need to back reference the part of the request you captured like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule forum/(.*) http://www.path.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

$X will reference a captured string in the matching part of the rewrite rule and output its value into the output string. Obviously, with the number corresponding to the group that was captured.

Comment: If placed in .htaccess this rule most likely will not work -- URL in first parameter of RewriteRule will have no leading slash present.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/forum/(.*)$ http://path.com/$1
```

Comment: If you are using `RedirectMatch` then no need for `RewriteEngine On` -- they are from 2 different modules.

Comment: I had a bash with ReWriteEngine On but had no luck at all